# Facebook Business PHP SDK : Cannot access an object not managed by the business owning this app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

I am trying to create a facebook Adaccount with [Facebook Business SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk). But when I use method `createAdAccount` it gives me an error. please see the image attached below. Here is the documentation about [adacount creation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/#Creating)

[image]

I am using `createAdAccount` like this.

```
public function createAdAccount() {
        //$params['name'] = "My test Partner";
        $params = ['name' => 'My test Partner',
            'currency' => 'USD', 
            'timezone_id' => 1, 
            'end_advertiser'=> 'NONE',
            'media_agency' => 'UNFOUND',
            'partner' => 'UNFOUND'
        ];
        $buisness = new Business('<buisness account id>');
        $adacount = $buisness->createAdAccount(['name'], $params);

        echo "<pre>"; print_r($adacount);
    }
```

**Update :** 
I also added my app id in my business account here.
[image]
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the reason behind this. This is due to the error because I haven't added the app into my business manager account. I added the app and it worked.
Please refer to the screenshot if you get the same issue.
You need to go into your business manager setting and add the app.
[image]

Hope this will help the needed person.

Comment: Is there any API for doing this?

Comment: I don't think there is any API for this, You need to do this manually .